# Is there a way to change the default post template selection for a specific category?

Tags: posts, page-template

When we add the new post,the default template is selected.
I want to change the default selected template to my custom template automatically before publishing or saving the post.
Here's an example:

Template Options by default:

Default Template (automatically selected)
My Template 1
My Template 2

Is there a WordPress way to change to:

Default Template
My Template 1 (automatically selected)
My Template 2

I was able to make it for all posts but wanted for specific category only

```
 function default_temp() {
 global $post;
 if ( 'post' == $post->post_type 
  //&& is_category('8')
  && 0 != count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) 
  && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID // Not the page 
  for listing posts
  && '' == $post->page_template // Only when page_template is not 
  set
  ) {
    $post->page_template = "single-post-game.php";
   }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'default_temp', 1);
```

Comment: is this in the classic editor, the block editor, or some other editor? Unless all your posts are already categorised when they're first created then this isn't about setting the default, but rather changing the page template when a category is set if it has not already been set. They sound similar and lead to the same result, but they are very different on a technical level. Is this what you are asking for? Or are you asking for _all_ posts to have my template 1 selected by default, even before they are categorised?

Comment: and if this always happens for all posts in that category no matter what, would it not be easier to remove my template 1 as an option, and do an `if post is in category load this template file, else, load default post template file`?

Comment: It's in classic editor, i want it for new posts which are not created yet. i was able to make it for all posts but wanted it for a specific category only.

Comment: so when a user selects that specific category you want it to change the selected option in the dropdown? That is not a default. Does this also mean if I select that category then deselect it that the chosen page template should change? There is no such thing as a post that has not been created yet, did you mean _a post that has not been published yet?_

Answer (score 1):

To set the default template for a specific category of posts in WordPress, you can modify your code to check the categories of the post before setting the default template.

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
function default_temp() {
  global $post;
  if ( 'post' == $post->post_type
    && 0 != count( get_page_templates( $post ) )
    && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID // Not the page for listing posts
    && '' == $post->page_template // Only when page_template is not set
  ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );

    // Set the default template for posts in the "8" category
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
      if ( '8' == $category->term_id ) {
        $post->page_template = "single-post-game.php";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'default_temp', 1 );
```

This will set the default template to "single-post-game.php" for posts in the category with the ID "8".

Answer (score 0):

It's success for me:

```
function wpse196289_default_page_template() {
    global $post;
    if (0 != count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) 
        && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID // Not the page for listing posts
        && '' == $post->page_template // Only when page_template is not set
    ) {
//print_r(get_page_templates( $post )); get list templates
//Array([Elementor Canvas] => elementor_canvas [Elementor Full Width] => elementor_header_footer [Theme] => elementor_theme)
        $post->page_template = "elementor_header_footer"; // set template you want
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wpse196289_default_page_template', 1);
```